# Div Mouse hover strikes the font within div in Javascript

Tags: javascript, firefox

This is my page URL. In this page recommended section I used javascript coding for mouse over and mouse out effect for the div. It works fine in chrome. But in Firefox when we mouse over the recommended section it strikes the font within the div. I don't know what is the mistake i done in my coding.

http://sample.com/domain.php?id=1&mview=48

Coding for the recommended page:

```
 <div id="mydiv" style="background:whitesmoke;height: 110px; width: 230px;margin-top: -20px;"  onmouseover="this.style.background='white';this.style.border='1px outset whitesmoke';this.style.textDecoration='line-through';" onmouseout="this.style.background='whitesmoke';this.style.border='none';">
    <div style="float: left;margin-top: 10px;margin-left: 5px;"><img src="upload/<?php echo $recommendimg['choice_image'] ?>" width="100" height="80"/></div>
    <div style="float: right; width: 110px;margin-top: 10px;height:95px;">
    <a id="pollnamerecompoll" href="pollpage.php?id=<?php echo $recommendedimgid; ?>&mview=<?php echo $mviews;?>">
    <div style="font-size: 12px;font-weight: 600;">Best <?php echo $recommendedrow['poll_name'] ?></div>
    </a>
    <a id='pollnamerecompoll' href='cusersprofile.php?oud=<?php echo $useridrec; ?>'>
    <div style="margin-top: 10px;font-size: 11px;">By <?php echo $getuserrec['first_name']; ?></div>
    </a>
    <div style="width: 110px;margin-top: 10px;">
    <div style="float:left;font-size: 11px;"><?php echo $mviews; ?> views</div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Anybody can please help to solve this problem. Thanks in advance

Comment: this.style.textDecoration='line-through'; have full div tag

Comment: Fixed the issue. Thanks for comment